# Drupal 7 views: Get NID in views using contextual filters

Tags: 7, nodes, views

Does anybody know how to get the nid from a node using contextual filters or filter criteria in views

WITHOUT using "Get id from url"? I was thinking about using PHP or getting it from a node-field.

My view is a block of comments that is to be placed together with a node. The comments needs to belong to the node and linked by node ID. In this case the "Get ID from url" wont work since the node itself is listed in another view.

It is a view-block (containing comments) inside of a node that is listed in a view.

Comment: Check out this blog post here http://highrockmedia.com/blog/using-views-contextual-filters-create-related-content-block-drupal-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading and displaying your view in the `node.tpl` or `node--<content-type>.tpl` file, you could supply the current node nid as an argument to your block view, then you can setup a contextual filter for Content: Nid. I would do something like this:

```
// get view
$view = views_get_view('YOUR_VIEW_NAME');
// set display for view
$view->set_display('YOUR_VIEW_BLOCK_NAME');
// set current node nid as argument to view
$view->set_arguments(array($node->nid));
// execute view
$view->execute();
// render view
print $view->render();
```

Comment: Since I already posted a working solution on stackoverflow I thought it would be a nice to do the same here=)